# Как сохранить объект в bundle?

Tags: java, android, классы, android-bundle

У меня есть класс,который я хочу сохранить в bundle.Я знаю что для этого нужно implements Parcelable.Там есть два метода:

```
    @Override
          public int describeContents ( ){
                        return 0;
                 }
```

И

```
    @Override
          public void writeToParcel ( Parcel p1, int p2 ){
                 }
```

Что сними нужно делать?

Comment: а как вы вообще этот bundle делаете?

Comment: Я сохраняю в bundle который получаю в методе onSaveInstanceState(Bundle b). При повороте экрана

Comment: если вы самостоятельно нашли ответ на заданный вами вопрос, то не поленитесь написать и ответ на него (кнопка "ответить на собственный вопрос"). Это позволит другим участникам решить аналогичную проблему быстрее

Answer (score 3):

У `Bundle` есть метод `putSerializable`. Если Ваш класс помечен аннотацией `Serializable`, Вы можете передать его экземпляр в `Bundle` с помощью этого метода.

```
myBundle.putSerializable("key", myObject);
```

Comment: А как мне в onRestoreInstanceState иноциализоровать объект из Serializable?

Comment: getSerializable?

Comment: Нужно использовать приведение? тoесть сделать так: myobject = (MyClass)getSerializable("key")?

Comment: При получении объекта, да.

Comment: Process: com.myApp.App, PID: 20416
07-23 15:29:27.938 20416 20416 E   AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.myApp.app.MainActivity) при закрытии.

Comment: Выложите Ваш код полностью. Желательно в отдельном вопросе. Без кода понять почему он не работает практически не возможно.

Comment: Для чего ,ведь не работает только часть кода а не весь?

Comment: Полный пример позволяет лучше понять суть проблемы и воспроизвести её. А, так это только заниматься "телепатией"..

Comment: Я сам решил эту проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Для передачи объектов в android есть два способа. Первый, это передавать Serializable, а второй Parcaleble. Serializable использует механизм рефлексии и не требует реализации, нужно только от него наследоваться. Parcelable требует реализации и в нем мы сохраняем каждое поле в так называемые ячейки памяти вручную и он намного быстрее. Для реализации нужно сделать класс наследником Parcelable и переопределить 2 метода.

В методе **writeToParcel** мы записываем наши поля у объект Parcelable для дальнейшего считывания в конструкторе, здесь важен порядок. В **describeContents**, 
если у вас POJO объект нужно возвращать 0.
Пример:

```
class TestModel(val name: String?, val age: Int) : Parcelable {

    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(parcel.readString(), parcel.readInt())

    override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel?, flags: Int) {
        dest?.writeString(name)
        dest?.writeInt(age)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int = 0

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<TestModel> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): TestModel {
            return TestModel(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<TestModel?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }

}
```